# Weak convergence in $L^2$ and uniform covergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I have this problem: let $f_n$ converge weakly to $f$ in $L^2[0,1]$ and let $$F_n(x)=\int_0^xf_n(t) \, \textrm{d}t,$$
$$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t) \, \textrm{d}t.$$
Then $F_n,F$ are continuous and $F_n$ converges uniformly to $F$.

Writing 
$$F_n(x)=\int_0^1 f_n(t) \mathbb{1}_{[0,x]} \, \textrm{d}t$$
and applying the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, the continuity of $F_n$ should be proved and analogously of $F$. But I don't know about the uniform convergence and how to use the weak convergence hypothesis..

Comment: A more bare-hands proof can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95260/is-this-functional-weakly-lower-semicontinuous/176028#176028)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible there is a simpler approach, but I'd proceed as follows.

1. Show that $F_n \to F$ pointwise.
2. It would suffice to show that $\{F_n\}$ is equicontinuous.  (Remember the Arzela-Ascoli theorem and/or its proof.)
3. Show that the weak convergence implies that $\sup_n \|f_n\|_{L^2} < \infty$.  (Use the uniform boundedness principle.)
4. Use the previous step together with Cauchy-Schwarz to estimate $|F_n(x) - F_n(y)|$ independently of $n$.

Comment: May I ask you what you mean exactly in point 2? Why would it suffice to show $\{F_n\}$ is equicontinuous? Consider for example the case in which the sequence $(f_n)_n$ is bounded in $L^2$. In that case, the $F_n$ would be equi-$\alpha$-holder, with $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$... How would you conclude? Thank you very much and sorry for disturbing.

Comment: @Romeo: It is a fact that a sequence of functions which is equicontinuous and converges pointwise on a compact set must converge uniformly.  This fact is contained in the proof of Arzela-Ascoli; you can also get it from the conclusion of Arzela-Ascoli by noting that compactness means the sequence has at least one uniform limit point, but pointwise convergence means this limit point is unique.

Comment: @Romeo: And by the way, $\{f_n\}$ *must* be bounded in $L^2$ by my point 3.